# Getting a Java factorial program with a while loop to keep repeating if the user enters with "y" and has the factorial part working as well

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, factorial

I am new to programming and I am trying to figure out how to get a java program to correctly run a factorial and ask the user if they would like to continue and input another number to use and display the factorial for that one. When the user inputs "y", the program is supposed to then ask for another number. If they select "n", the program should terminate. I've been working on this code for a day and still haven't figured out where I am going wrong in the code to make it solve factorials correctly while looping. Can someone please help me?

```js
 int i = 0;
 int factorial = 1;
 int input;
 char ind = 'y';

      
 while (ind == 'y') {
      System.out.println("Please enter in a number to determine it's factorial: ");
  input = scan.nextInt();
   scan.nextLine();
if  ( i<= input) {
 i=input;
   i++;
  factorial = factorial * i;
  System.out.println(" the factorial of: " + input + " is " + factorial);
}System.out.println(" Do you want to continue? (y/n) :");
 ind = scan.nextLine().charAt(0); 
}
System.out.println("goodbye.");
 } }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: You need to describe what is wrong. Does `ind = scan.nextLine().charAt(0); scan.nextLine();` help?

Comment: You need a _loop_ to compute a factorial. Instead of `if (i <= input)...`, you should be thinking `while (i <= input)...`

Comment: The code I have now doesn't calculate the factorial correctly. I'm not fully understanding what loops connect with what loops to compute this problem.

Comment: Although I tried the while (i <= input). the factorial calculations do not compute. With the code that is already posted, it just doesn't calculate factorials correctly. Instead it just adds them. So if I wanted the factorial of 5, the answer would be 6. Which is incorrect.

Comment: the two next.line codes help work my way to the second loop and also helps loop it back.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, you need to know what a factorial is.

n! = n * (n-1)!

That's important to understand. The factorial if 5 is 5 times the factorial of 4. That's actually kind of cool and very useful. So you can write a function that does that.

```
long factorial(long n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

So what you do is define a method similar to the above. And then in your loop where you ask them to enter a number, you call this method. It calls itself as needed to do the calculation for you.

There are other ways. You can do a for-loop.

```
long result = 0;
for (long val = 2; val <= n; ++val) {
    result = result * val;
}
```

But the recursive method is kind of cool.

Comment: I understand that the equation of the factorial. I'm needing to know where it is needed in my program for it to compute.  I tried placing it in multiple places. Currently, the answers I get are either 1 or 0.

Comment: Your code to compute the factorial doesn't do any sort of looping, which is why you're getting poor results. Basically, a good chuck of if (i <= input) is flawed. I'm not even sure what you're trying to do with that. Instead, get your input, then calculate the factorial using the method I outlined above, and print the results.